# Duplicate pdf icon images are showing for no reason

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to make a create your profile page with an option for them to upload CV. Problem is, its showing way tooo many pdf icons. Can anyone help me out? I'm trying to make it so one shows up only. Theyre also acting all as single files that all lead to an error when clicked on.

Thank you

```
<style>
    a[href$=".pdf"]:before {
        content: url(http://www.wischenbart.com/img/pdf_icon.gif);
    }
</style>
...


    <div class="row">
    @if(get_file_uploads($client['id']) != null)
    @foreach(get_file_uploads($client['id']) as $upload)
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
        <ul class="documents">
           <li><a href="/download/{{$client['id']}}/{{$upload}}.pdf"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

...

```
    <div class="tab-pan-title"> CV Uploads </div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
    @if(get_cv_uploads($client['email']) != null)
    @foreach(get_cv_uploads($client['email']) as $upload)
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
        <ul class="documents">
            <li><a href="/download_cv/{{$client['email']}}/{{$upload}}.pdf"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @else
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
        <h4>No Cv Uploaded</h4>
    </div>
    @endif
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <form action="update_client_file" method="GET">
            <button id="myCvBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Upload CV</button>
      
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

[imagesof icons showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqIyJ.png)

Comment: It is a foreach loop, so it seems normal to me that you see multiple icons. You should also check your html. the li tag is inside a div tag instead of a ul tag...

Comment: Hello, thank you for explaining that to me, I've just realized it is. However,  I've swapped them around but all it did was increase the number of icons somehow.

Comment: You should update the question with the changed code. The reason why the number of items increases could be that you saved new items. Consider dumping get_cv_uploads($client['email']) by using @dump() so you can see what the output is.

Comment: i've updated the code. I tried inserting ul tag only instead of li tag within ui but both have the same output. 
I tried doing what you said but internal errors just started coming up .

Comment: you use @foreach(get_cv_uploads($client['email']) as $upload) so for every item in get_cv_uploads it shows a LI

Comment: This has actually helped me quite a lot, thank you so much. 
I'm just trying to figure out what I can replace that with. But it's definitely the main reason for the many icons.

Comment: I think you need to look at the reason why there are multiple uploads returned. Like are you adding uploads instead of replacing them, Is your get query wrong or maybe there can be multiple uploads, in the last case the output is correct.

Comment: Each person that creates an account can upload how many CVs they want. In fact, when they want to 'edit' their profile, which literally looks almost the same as creating a new profile, there is no problem with duplication of icons. This problem only occurs on the create a new profile page.